# when no record found error #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: mysql, sql

when I execute this Stored Procedure, if record found there is no error and it returns rows, but if no record found there is this error, and there is no foreign key in that table, still I tried it by adding

> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

at beginning of SP
and
at end of SP

> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

But it did't work

Stored Procedure :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `find_location`
(IN `location` VARCHAR(50)) 
NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM properties
   WHERE properties_location LIKE concat('%',location,'%');
END
```

**Error**

> Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> > 1.Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)
> >     SQL query: Edit Edit
>
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

**Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `properties` (
  `properties_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `properties_title` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `properties_country` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `properties_state` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `properties_city` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `properties_location` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `properties_contact` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `properties_agent` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `properties_floorarea` decimal(15,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `properties_bedrooms` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `properties_bathrooms` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `properties_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `properties_furnishing` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `properties_userid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `properties_usertype` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `properties_isapproved` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `properties_isactive` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `properties_cr_dt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  `properties_md_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `properties_description` varchar(19000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `properties_img` varchar(600) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Your error says "Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25) " But I didn't find ON in your stored procedure. Please explain.

Comment: Your issue is not inside this SP - it is in the code which invokes the SP. Also, you do not need to enable/disable FK checks - it makes no difference here.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I tried to invoke in mysql also by writing **call find_location('test');** but still same error

Comment: @Suresh I am also not getting it, why is it showing near "ON" error

Comment: @KDN: please share table structure  mrrealestate_properties  with some sample data to cross verify.

Comment: @Suresh I have Updated my question with table

Comment: Check if you have another procedure with the same name SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' AND ROUTINE_NAME in ('find_location','FIND_FUNCTION');

Comment: @KDN: Sorry for late reply, Please check my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please create procedure again as given below:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `find_location`(IN `location` VARCHAR(50))
NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM properties WHERE properties_location LIKE CONCAT('%',location,'%');
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I tested calling procedure as below command and didn't find any error , in case no record found in table.

```
CALL find_location('India');
```

Please check and confirm. Hope it works!